# std::bind a std::shared_ptr parameter won't increase use_count

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Foo{
    Foo():
        m_p(std::make_shared<int>())
    {}
    Foo(const Foo &foo)
    {
        printf("copy\n");
    }
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_p;
};

void func(Foo foo)
{}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::function<void (void)> f = std::bind(func, foo);
    printf("use count : %ld\n", foo.m_p.use_count());
    f();
}
```

got result:

```
copy
copy
use count : 1
copy
```

Since Foo is copied, I thought m_p's use_count should be 2.

I am using clang++

Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)

I compile the code in debug mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, your copy constructor isn't copying `m_p`:

```
Foo(const Foo &foo):
    m_p{foo.m_p}
{
    printf("copy\n");
}
```

Second, your `bind` results in a temporary which is immediately discarded; you should capture it (e.g. into an `auto`):

```
auto bar = std::bind(func, foo);
```

Comment: I know these issues. First, copy constructor will call the member's copy constructor by default. Second, temporary variable will cause the copy constructor invoke twice.

Comment: @user1429171 First: it *would*, if you hadn't provided your own copy constructor that prevents the default one from being generated; second: the copy constructor is invoked, but the destructor is invoked as well, decrementing the use count (it isn't a high water mark).

Answer (score 1):

the results of `std::bind` are not stored in a variable and are immediately discarded.